# ASP. NET Page Cannot be displayed error when the application is idle for long time

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I've developed an ASP.net Application.
I've accessed it and left it idle in my web browser for a long time. After a long duration, when I try to access the Application, it is redirecting me to "Page Cannot be Displayed" error page, Instead of redirecting to Login page.

This behavior is intermittent. In most of the scenarios, it is working as expected(Redirecting to Login Page).

Default timeout is set to 20 mins..
Forms authentication timeout is set to 20 mins.

I'm using .net version 4.0

Comment: can you be please be more specific because I do not understand whats your problem - you do not wish to redirect to login, but to some other page ? this is what you look for ?

Comment: Hi Aristos, Thanks for your response. Ideally it should be redirected to Login Page. Unfortunately in some scenarios, instead of redirecting to Login Page, it is displaying an error page "Page Cannot be displayed"

Comment: In most of the scenarios, it is working as expected. It is happening rarely. But We could notice this issue atleast once in a day.

Comment: If you are logged in and the session is expired, and you use the session on some variables is possible to get a null exception before the check that the page can not be displayed and need to redirect to login

Comment: Is it possible that your application pool is recycling itself and taking a longer time to load up than your browser is prepared to wait? Try changing recycling settings in your application pool properties in IIS.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest installing something like ELMAH (http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) to catch these exceptions and see what is causing it.

Perhaps the page you are redirecting to on session expiry is reliant on something in session that is no longer available or something ?  If you install ELMAH this should point you in the right direction.